# DFA for integer in binary that is: 1mod5

Tags: finite-automata, state-machine, deterministic

I can create a DFA for 0mod5, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the DFA for 1mod5. For examples such as 11=1mod5, my DFA works. However, when I have something like 16, 15 is 01111 and I don't know how to make that into a 16.

Answer (score 1):

Start in state `s := 0`. Every new symbol `n` you read, go to state `s := (2s + n) % 5`. Accept if you are in state `s = 1`.